# How to extend AppDelegate via "extension AppDelegate { }" using Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

I have an app which has AppDelegate as usually.
I have an extension for that AppDelegate, something like this:

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func doSomething(msg: String)
    {
        print("done something \(msg)")
    }
}
```

How can I put that extension into separate cocoapod and integrate it via **pod install**
The problem is that when I add that code directly to some source file to be delivered by cocoapod then I get error:

*Use of undeclared type 'AppDelegate'*

Which obviously means that it can't find the AppDelegate file as it does not exist in pod's source. So how do I tell my pod that this is an extension of the class that itself is somewhere in the project to where it will be integrated.

Comment: Why do you want to extend `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Just to add specific functionality. AppDelegate itself is just a name of the class as a sample. It could be any name eg SomeOtherClass.

Comment: Pods compile into modules, and modules have to be able to compile. This can't compile because it doesn't know what `AppDelegate` is, or even what module it's in. You'd need the pod to be dependent on the app. This approach can't work. You'll need to back up to what deeper problem you're trying to solve and go another way.

Comment: Yep, @RobNapier, that is where I did end up either but I still posted a question just to get it confirmed or overruled by some possible hack. But even if there is anything out there then it is most likely some non-cocoapods way.

Answer (score 2):

Just extend the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, which `AppDelegate` conforms to:

```
extension UIApplicationDelegate {
    public func doSomething(text: String) {
        print("text:", text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahaa, Nice idea! I will try if it works with cocoapods.

Comment: @eyebleed have you found the solution